# Dynamic sized collectionView cell causing visibility issue - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, dynamic, uicollectionview, cgsize

I have a 3 columns and multiple rows Collection View. In my `sizeForItemAtIndexPath`, I return a dynamic `CGSize` like this :

```
return CGSizeMake(_sponsoredCollectionView.frame.size.width/3 - 7, (_sponsoredCollectionView.frame.size.width/3 - 7 + nameHeight + cuisineHeight + addressHeight + timingHeight + paddings));
```

But with the above size, my last cell is not being displayed ( I don't understand why, because the height that is being returned is similar to previous cells and there is a lot of space for it to be shown, as previous cells did), see screenshot below :
[image]

And when I hardcode the size to the following :

```
return CGSizeMake(_sponsoredCollectionView.frame.size.width/3 - 7,250);
```

It is shown (cell with KEKOU title, but obviously with a lot of empty spaces above and below due to hardcode 250 height, see screenshot below :
[image]

**Also, I am doing the following, for the CollectionView to resize according to cells after realoading**

```
[_sponsoredCollectionView reloadData];

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
  _sponsoredCollectionViewHeightConstraint.constant = _sponsoredCollectionView.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize.height + 0;
});
```

I am unable to understand what is the issue :S Please Help!

Comment: Pleaes can someone help? Been trying too long but unable to solve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally after one full night of trial and error and research, I solved it by just changing the `_sponsoredCollectionViewHeightConstraint.constant` inside a `performBatchUpdates` like this :

```
[_sponsoredCollectionView reloadData];

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                        [self.sponsoredCollectionView performBatchUpdates:^{
                            _sponsoredCollectionViewHeightConstraint.constant = _sponsoredCollectionView.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize.height + 5;//_sponsoredCollectionView.contentSize.height + 5;
                        } completion:nil];
                    });
```